# iOS 13.3.1 dyld: Library not loaded

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate, dyld

Not a question per se but i've been having trouble with an iOS app i'm developing: Working fine in simulator and device and then all of sudden stopped working on the physical device. It crashes on startup with and error that begins with iOS 13.3.1 dyld: Library not loaded, following will be one of you pod's name and in the middle you'll find some reference to code signing certificates.

For those of asking about the simulator do remember the simulator does not need code signing certificates only a physical device does.

Not a problem go to google and search for an answer, well there isn't one. Aparently this "bug" is directly linked to "Free" apple developer accounts. If you have a paid account you wont experience this. If you have a free account, all you have to do is downgrade your device to before the last update, so downgrade from 13.3.1 to something lower and it will work again.
Just tried it on my other iPad and it worked.

So aparently this did happen in early 13 betas and then Apple fixed it and now it's doing it again in 13.3.1 so while we wait for apple to roll out something and fix this just debug on a device lower than 13.3.1.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Yeah it looks like the problem with  free Apple ID provisional profile. wait for iOS 13.3.2 may be POD related issue should be solved

Some Google search say "removing use_frameworks! and adding use_modular_headers! worked"

But in my case comment #use_frameworks! and again update the pod work for me

Comment: Commenting out use_frameworks will work depending on the pods, for instance if you use google’s firebase it wont compile without it so in my case i do have to wait for an update since i do need it

Answer (score 1):

Having the same problem, with pods!!!  I got a reasonable response to running when I changed the 'link binaries with library' status from 'required' to 'optional'.